# Convert Map to inline element, text XML

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-serialization, simple-framework

Considering the following Map structure (JSON for simplification):

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
}
```

Using the SimpleXML framework for Java, how can I convert to the following XML considering that the map is a class variable of Parent.

```
<Parent>
  <key1>value1</key1>
  <key2>value2</key2>
</Parent>
```

I have looked at the SimpleXML tutorials around inline mapping etc but it falls short of a solution. I think I will need to implement some kind of custom serializer. ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the proper structure should be:

```
<Parent>
  <mapFieldOfTheParentClass>
    <key1>value1</key1>
    <key2>value2</key2>
  </mapFieldOfTheParentClass>
</Parent>
```

That's because Your class could have a field named "key1" and it wouldn't be possible to differentiate it from map's key. But if you are certain that you want yours structure a custom serializer would work as long as no conflicts happen.

Comment: I agree in general but the server I am communicating to expects the format I have outlined. The messages are explicitly specified so a conflict/duplicate key is an erroneous result of my implementation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I will need to implement some kind of custom serializer.

In this case you wont get around this. But fortunately it's not complicated.

Here's an example:

```
@Root(name = "Parent")
@Convert(Example.ParentConverter.class)
public class Example
{
    private Map<String, String> values;

    // ...

    static class ParentConverter implements Converter<Example>
    {

        @Override
        public Example read(InputNode node) throws Exception
        {
            Example value = new Example();
            value.values = new HashMap<>();
            InputNode next;

            while( ( next = node.getNext() ) != null )
            {
               value.values.put(next.getName(), next.getValue());
            }

            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(OutputNode node, Example value) throws Exception
        {
            // Implement to support writing too
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }
    }
}
```

The `@Convert` requires eg. an `AnnotationStrategy`:

```
Serializer ser = new Persister(new AnnotationStrategy());
Example e = ser.read(Example.class, xml); // xml = input xml
```

---

### Edit:

Possible implementation for a map-field-only converter:

```
@Override
public void write(OutputNode node, Map<String, String> value) throws Exception
{
    final OutputNode parent = node.getParent();

    if( !value.isEmpty() )
    {
        boolean first = true;

        for( Map.Entry<String, String> e : value.entrySet() )
        {
            if( first == true )
            {
                node.setName(e.getKey());
                node.setValue(e.getValue());
                // Remove generated 'class' attribute for collections
                node.getAttributes().remove("class");
                first = false;
            }
            else
            {
                parent.getChild(e.getKey()).setValue(e.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle empty maps
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is is possible to only apply the convert to the values member of Example and not the entire class. I would prefer to only handle that field. Also, I was asking about serialisation but I can figure out the other side. Thanks.

Comment: You can do so, just implement a converter for that field's type, add `@Convert(...)` *and* `@Element` annotation. But this will possible be tricky to implement for *reading*. But if you only want to *write* (sorry, misread your question) it'll work. Tip: The Converter will create a wrapper element for the map. To fix this just modify it to be the first value and remove the `class` attribute. If you get into trouble, please report back here.

Comment: I added an example how to implement the converter (write only).